# Methods in Default Protocol extension executed on unit testing always

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I have a protocol with the default implementation in the extension of that protocol. When I try to create a concrete mock object of that protocol to unit test, the default implementation always gets executed. I am not able to figure why. Any help would be appreciated. I am on xcode 11.3

```
protocol ABC: AnyObject {
 func doSomething()
}

extension ABC {
 func doSomething() {
   print("Did Something")
 }

}


final class ClassToBeTested {

    var abc: ABC?

    func methodToBeTested() {
       abc?.doSomething()
    }
}
```

**In Test Target**

```
final class MockABC: ABC {
   func doSomething() {
     print("Did Something in Test Target")
  }
}

final class Tests: XCTestCase {

   func testMethod() {
     let obj = ClassTobeTested()
     // abc property is of type protocol ABC
     obj.abc = MockABC()

    *This line calls the default implementation of the protocol of ABC and not the 
     implementation in MockABC class - verifiable by breakpoints and print statements*

     obj.methodToBeTested()

  }

}
```

I have read the `static` dispatch which happens in such cases, but could not find any particular reason to this. Kindly help.

Comment: It works on my side, the mock method is called. Maybe you have a typo in the original code that results in the behaviour you noticed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the protocol.

```
protocol ABC: AnyObject {
    func doSomething() -> String
}

extension ABC {
    func doSomething() -> String {
        return "Did Something"
    }
}

final class ClassToBeTested {

    private let abc: ABC

    init(abc: ABC) {
        self.abc = abc
    }

    func methodToBeTested() -> String {
       return abc.doSomething()
    }
}
```

**Testing Target**

```
final class ABCMock: ABC {
    func doSomething() {
        print("Did Something in Test Target")
    }
}

final class ClassToBeTestedTests: XCTestCase {

    private let mockABC: MockABC = .init()

    func test_methodToBeTested() {
        let obj = ClassTobeTested()
        XCTAssertEqual(obj.methodToBeTested(), "Did Something in Test Target")
    }
}
```

This snippet of code it's very simple, but according to your question this is the best way.